# How to use Swift Package Manager(SPM) in cli?

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

I'm a newbie to swift. I don't know and I can't find out how to use Swift Package Manager in command line.

Is there any equivalent stuff to `Podfile` `pod install` and `pod update`? How to add a local package dependency to the project?

Xcode SPM GUI is totally unusable because of some proxy problems.

Comment: https://www.swift.org/getting-started/#using-the-package-manager ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### I have followed those steps to solve the problem.

1. set git HTTP proxy

```
git config --global http.proxy http://0.0.0.0:1087
git config --global http.proxy socks5://0.0.0.0:1080
```

2. set ssh proxy for host

Append those lines at the end of `~/.ssh/config` to add a socks5 proxy

```
Host github.com
ProxyCommand nc -X 5 -x 0.0.0.0:1080 %h %p
```

3. use xcodebuild command to resolve package dependencies

Remember you must add the `-scmProvider system` option to force xcodebuild to use system git and git configurations, or it will use the xcode built-in git **which will never go through the proxy**.

```
xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -scmProvider system
```

#### Some references here:

- [Building Swift Packages or Apps that Use Them in Continuous Integration Workflows](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/building_swift_packages_or_apps_that_use_them_in_continuous_integration_workflows)